# Saving Excel and .pdf into memory stream

Tags: vb.net, excel

How can I save an Excel or PDF file, created using VB.NET, into memory stream without saving the file to disk?

Comment: Your question states VB.NET, but your tag is VB6. They are very different languages so which one do you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm using vb.net

Comment: What API(s) are you using to generate the EXCEL/PDF files?

Comment: I'm just saving it as ".pdf"